# How to create signed urls for webpages on CloudFront with links to other CSS/JS files?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I've created signed urls using cloudfront for my webpage, which looks like this:

https://abcXXX.cloudfront.net/index.html?Expires=1510886661&Signature=XXX&Key-Pair-Id=XXX

This webpage is stored on Amazon S3.

Although the webpage itself loads fine, the problem I have is that it links to a number of other files such as CSS and JS files.

e.g. consider the following HTML document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="js/foo.js"/>
    </head>   
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

This means I get a lot of the following in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

The obvious solution is to set cookies. So I did the following:

```
$sdk = new Aws\Sdk( [
    'region' => 'eu-west-2',
    'version' => 'latest',
] );
$cloudFront = $sdk->createCloudFront();
$domain = "xxx.cloudfront.net";
$resourceKey = "https://{$domain}/index.html";

$signedCookieCannedPolicy = $cloudFront->getSignedCookie([
    'url'         => $resourceKey,
    'expires'     => time() + 60,
    'private_key' => 'private.pem',
    'key_pair_id' => 'XXX'
]);

foreach ($signedCookieCannedPolicy as $name => $value) {
    setcookie($name, $value, 0, "", $domain, true, true);
}
wp_redirect( $resourceKey ); // wordpress redirect
die();
```

However, when redirected I got:

```
<Error>
    <Code>MissingKey</Code>
    <Message>
        Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value
    </Message>
</Error>
```

When inspecting the cookies, it seems like it was never past on. This might be because I think you cannot set cookies from one domain (say from https://mybookshop.com) to another domain.

How can I solve my problem?

**UPDATE**

I tried manually adding the cookies, and although the main index.html file opened fine, I now get the following error on the console:

```
GET https://XXX.cloudfront.net/css/ereader.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Comment: why are you protecting these resources that should be public?

Comment: No I don't want this webpage public. They are HTML ebooks which I only want people who I've authorised to access.

Comment: no, the css and js are not protected resources even if the html is. You can just make them public. You should have a clear division between protected resources and public resources.

Comment: I wanted those files protected as well to be honest as it contained private commercial code.

Comment: then it sounds like you should lock it up on a hard drive it a safe. haha seriously you download commercial private code everyday of your life everytime you visit a website.  If it can't be on people's computers then you can't send it to them ever. I promise nobody is unminifying your css and js and stealing your methods, and you couldn't stop me if I wanted to.

Comment: The page I'm securing is a ebook. It contains private stuff such as images and pdf. We use many obfustruction tools to make it hard to read the content, Some of that content is in JS files. Hence we would also like to secure the CSS, JS, JPEG files. We want to prevent anyone downloading these files unless they have purchased it. Rgardless of my usecase, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes so you protect the images and pdfs... not the JS or CSS, hence why I said you should have clear division between protected and public content. You're not actually making anything more secure by doing this. You're just adding needless difficulty. Anyway, this isn't doable in CF / S3 security the way you're approaching it.  You'd need to pass the HTML page through a server that can dynamically sign the resource URLs.

Comment: So I would also have to sign my JPEGs I assume as well

Comment: I will typically get the signed image urls from a server via ajax and dynamically insert them in js, as images are very commonly a protected resource, ie users don't want their personal photos exposed to the world. You could make a base JS file public that does this and extend this concept to the other resources

Comment: You'll need `$resourceKey = "https://{$domain}/*";` to allow access to everything, and if everything is not what you want, things do get more complex.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That just gives me a flat out 403 error. Are you sure you can do that?

Comment: Have you found solution?